# Python while loop issue - repeats unexpectantly

Tags: python, while-loop, break, continue

I'm trying to write code to ask a series of questions and if the user answers "No", then the while loop breaks and a statement prints.  This part of my code works.  However if the use answers "Yes" to the first question, it just keeps asking the same question repeatedly.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

```
#The first set of questions is to screen whether or not the assignment should be further graded as if 
#they failed to complete any of the four following tasks, they will receive a "0" for their grade.
answer = "Yes"
while answer == "Yes":
    answer = input("Is the assignment a single uncompressed .py file?  Yes or No: ")
    if answer != "Yes":
        break
        answer = input("Did the student include both their name and date?  Yes or No: ")
    if answer != "Yes":
        break
        honor_statement = input("Did the student include the honor statement, 'I have not given or 
received any unauthorized assistance on this assignment.'?  Yes or No: ")
    if answer != "Yes":
        break
        youtube_link = input("Did the student include a link to an unlisted 3 minute YouTube video 
presenting the code and answering the assigned questions?  Yes or No: ")
    if answer != "Yes":
        break
print("The student is awarded a grade of '0' because he or she failed to complete one or more of the 
requisite assignment items in full.")
```

Comment: Every `if` statement after the first question is checking if `answer != "Yes"`, meaning they'll all be skipped, and the loop will start over at the beginning. The code is doing exactly what you wanted - what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: Anything after a `break` statement at the same indentation level will not be executed. Is the indentation correct?

Comment: Where are you confused?  It's doing exactly what you *told* it to do: if that answer is `Yes`, skip each of the following questions in turn, and repeat the loop.  What functionality do you expect?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect your actual output *and* your desired output.

Comment: Well I'm not sure I specified correctly.  I'm trying to stop the code in the event any of the questions is answered "No" since the user has to have "Yes" to all questions in order to not receive a "0" score.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. You don't want to ask the same questions repeatedly, you just want to ask 4 independent questions. So use nested `if` statements.

Assign a different variable from each question, and then test them all at the end.

```
uncompressed = input("Is the assignment a single uncompressed .py file?  Yes or No: ")
if uncompressed == "Yes":
    namedate = input("Did the student include both their name and date?  Yes or No: ")
    if namedate == "Yes":
        honor_statement = input("Did the student include the honor statement, 'I have not given or received any unauthorized assistance on this assignment.'?  Yes or No: ")
        if honor_statement == "Yes":
            youtube_link = input("Did the student include a link to an unlisted 3 minute YouTube video presenting the code and answering the assigned questions?  Yes or No: ")
            if youtube_link == "Yes":
if uncompressed != "Yes" or namedate != "Yes" or honor_statement != "Yes" or youtube_link != "Yes": 
    print("The student is awarded a grade of '0' because he or she failed to complete one or more of the requisite assignment items in full.")
```